# Link error while building a C++ Unit test project in VS.NET 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, linker-errors

I am trying to build a very simple C++ unit test project.  The setup is just so happened to be exactly the same as what this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jsocha/archive/2010/11/19/writing-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-for-native-c.aspx?PageIndex=2) described.  I built a static library TestLib.lib and a C++ unit test project called TestProject.  Both projects are using platform toolset v100.

The Testlib contains only one class.

**BaseClass.h**

```
#pragma once 

class BaseClass
{
public:
    void Method1();
};
```

**BaseClass.cpp**

```
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

void BaseClass::Method1()
{
    list<int> dummy(0);
    cout << "Hello world";
}
```

The TestProject has only one test case.

```
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include <list>
.
.
.
[TestMethod]
void TestMethod1()
{
    BaseClass b;
    b.Method1();
};
```

It looks like if I have a `#include <list>` after `#include "BaseClass.h"` (in the test.cpp) I will have the following link error.  If I take out the `#include <list>`, I have no link error at all.

```
TestLib.lib(BaseClass.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification
MSVCMRT.lib(locale0_implib.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >): (0x0200003d).
MSVCMRT.lib(locale0_implib.obj) : error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (8013118D) : Inconsistent layout information in duplicated types (std.basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >): (0x02000063).
LINK : fatal error LNK1255: link failed because of metadata errors
```

The link error will be gone if I add one more line to the test program, like this:

```
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include <list>
.
.
.
[TestMethod]
void TestMethod1()
{
    std::list<int> dummy(0);
    BaseClass b;
    b.Method1();
};
```

However, now, I have two link warnings.  I am not sure whether they are related to the previous link errors.

```
TestLib.lib(BaseClass.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
```

Can anybody explain why?  Do I miss something obvious here?

Comment: Does the error only show up when compiling the Debug configuration?  If so, it may be related to your C++ run-time library linkage:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vclanguage/thread/e5a78770-4d99-40b7-951f-e4466d2744a8

Comment: @Jollymorphic Bingo, you got it.  I just made it working by changing the library to use debug CRT.  Please post it as an answer.  It is really a shame on Microsoft.  Why it is set to the wrong CRT when it comes out of the box?  I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the error only show up when compiling the Debug configuration? If so, it may be related to your C++ run-time library linkage:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vclanguage/thread/e5a78770-4d99-40b7-951f-e4466d2744a8